# Mysql database query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to fetch data from mysql in three 3 tables. I am using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. This is my query:

```
SELECT cms_addresses.address1 as add1, 
  cms_addresses.email as ademail, 
  cms_addresses.city as adcity, 
  cms_addresses.clientid 
  cms_addresses.country as adcountry, 
  cms_addresses.province as adprovince, 
  cms_addresses.postal as adprovince, 
  cms_delivery_info.d_address1, 
  cms_delivery_info.d_city, 
  cms_delivery_info.d_country, 
  cms_delivery_info.d_province, 
  cms_delivery_info.d_postal, 
  cms_orders.id, 
  cms_orders.cdate, 
  cms_orders.message 
FROM cms_addresses 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cms_delivery_info 
  ON cms_addresses.clientid = cms_delivery_info.d_clientid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cms_orders = cms_addresses.clientid = cms_orders.clientid
WHERE cms_orders.id = 10
  and cms_addresses.addresstypeid = 1
```

Problem is that this query is not running and gives me that error.

> Not unique table/alias: 'cms_addresses'

Please help me out to resolve this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You had a syntactical error in the second left join, where there was '=' after the table name
TRy this::

```
SELECT 
cms_addresses.address1 as add1, 
cms_addresses.email as ademail, 
cms_addresses.city as adcity, 
cms_addresses.clientid, 
cms_addresses.country as adcountry, 
cms_addresses.province as adprovince, 
cms_addresses.postal as adprovince, 
cms_delivery_info.d_address1, 
cms_delivery_info.d_city, 
cms_delivery_info.d_country, 
cms_delivery_info.d_province, 
cms_delivery_info.d_postal, 
cms_orders.id, 
cms_orders.cdate, 
cms_orders.message 

FROM cms_addresses 

LEFT OUTER JOIN cms_delivery_info ON cms_addresses.clientid = cms_delivery_info.d_clientid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cms_orders on cms_addresses.clientid = cms_orders.clientid 
WHERE cms_orders.id = 10 and cms_addresses.addresstypeid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

put a comma between `cms_addresses.clientid` and `cms_addresses.country AS adcountry` and see if it works

```
SELECT  cms_addresses.address1 AS add1,
        cms_addresses.email AS ademail,
        cms_addresses.city AS adcity,
        cms_addresses.clientid,                  // add comma here
        cms_addresses.country AS adcountry,
        cms_addresses.province AS adprovince,
        cms_addresses.postal AS adprovince,
        cms_delivery_info.d_address1,
        cms_delivery_info.d_city,
        cms_delivery_info.d_country,
        cms_delivery_info.d_province,
        cms_delivery_info.d_postal,
        cms_orders.id,
        cms_orders.cdate,
        cms_orders.message
FROM    cms_addresses
        LEFT JOIN cms_delivery_info
                ON cms_addresses.clientid = cms_delivery_info.d_clientid
        LEFT JOIN cms_orders 
                // use ON instead of = (equal sign) here
                ON cms_addresses.clientid = cms_orders.clientid
WHERE   cms_orders.id = 10 AND cms_addresses.addresstypeid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `SELECT` you have at some point:

```
cms_addresses.clientid cms_addresses.country as adcountry,
```

which looks like you missed a `,` somewhere?

In your `FROM` you have:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN cms_orders = cms_addresses.clientid = cms_orders.clientid
```

which again I'm guessing is a typo (first `=` should be a `ON`).

The message you are getting means you are reusing the table `cms_addresses` in your `JOIN` chain and you are not giving it an alias, which is mandatory for disambiguation, but in your case it's weird because you don't have `cms_addresses` more than once in the `FROM` clause.

I'd try rewriting the query giving aliases to all tables. Also enable full logging and check what really reaches Mysql.